# How to read hive ACID ORC table dump

Tags: pyspark, hive, orc, acid

I try to read a hive ACID ORC table dump file with pyspark and hive.
The dump file schema is as followed.

```
struct<
  operation: int,
  originalTransaction: bigInt,
  bucket: int,
  rowId: bigInt,
  currentTransaction: bigInt,
  row: struct<...>
>
```

#### 1. pyspark

When trying with pyspark with version > 3.0, but it's impossible to read the row column.
If I save the orc data with dataframe and try to read the 'row' column, the error occurred.

```py
# Create SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Read Hive ACID ORC File") \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()

# Hive ACID ORC path
orc_file_path = "hdfs://~~"

# read ORC file
df = spark.read.format("orc").load(orc_file_path)
df.show(truncate=False, n=5)

# error occurred here!
df.select('row').show()
```

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o285.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 15.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 15.0 (TID 39) (ac3d0x2011.bdp.bdata.ai executor 1): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$StructTreeReader.nextBatch(TreeReaderFactory.java:2055)
    at org.apache.orc.impl.RecordReaderImpl.nextBatch(RecordReaderImpl.java:1324)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcColumnarBatchReader.nextBatch(OrcColumnarBatchReader.java:196)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcColumnarBatchReader.nextKeyValue(OrcColumnarBatchReader.java:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec$$anon$1.hasNext(DataSourceScanExec.scala:503)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.columnartorow_nextBatch_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:755)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:898)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:898)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2258)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2207)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2206)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2206)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1079)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1079)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1079)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2445)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2387)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2376)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:868)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2196)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2217)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2236)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:472)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:425)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3696)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$head$1(Dataset.scala:2722)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3687)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3685)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2722)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2929)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:301)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:338)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$StructTreeReader.nextBatch(TreeReaderFactory.java:2055)
    at org.apache.orc.impl.RecordReaderImpl.nextBatch(RecordReaderImpl.java:1324)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcColumnarBatchReader.nextBatch(OrcColumnarBatchReader.java:196)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcColumnarBatchReader.nextKeyValue(OrcColumnarBatchReader.java:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec$$anon$1.hasNext(DataSourceScanExec.scala:503)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.columnartorow_nextBatch_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:755)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:898)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:898)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more

(<class 'py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError'>, Py4JJavaError('An error occurred while calling o285.showString.\n', JavaObject id=o286), <traceback object at 0x7f5464fe0108>)
```

#### 2. hive

If I define external hive table with the schema as followed,

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fdp__db_ec_tmp_test.payment_type_filter_file_full
(
    operation           INT,
    originaltransaction BIGINT,
    bucket              INT,
    rowid               BIGINT,
    currenttransaction  BIGINT,
    `row`               STRUCT<id: INT, value: STRING>
)
    STORED AS ORC
    LOCATION '{HDFS_LOCATION}'
;
```

```
java.io.IOException: org.apache.orc.impl.SchemaEvolution$IllegalEvolutionException: ORC does not support type conversion from file type string (12) to reader type struct<id: int, value: string>(12)
```

Thank you for your assistance in advance !!!!

Comment: see ORC [configurations](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-orc.html#configuration). try tinkering with the impl and/or mergeSchema options.